# Is there a keyboard shortcut in Firefox to paste the Unix "primary selection" clipboard, not the Firefox one?

Tags: linux, firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, clipboard

I run Linux, and am used to selecting text with the mouse to copy and pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> to paste. (This uses an alternate clipboard known as the "Primary Selection".)

This seems to work in every application besides Firefox. Firefox uses a different clipboard, where <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> copies and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> pastes. Is there a keystroke or configuration change I can do to make Firefox paste from the Unix "primary selection" clipboard -- the one it pastes from when I click the middle mouse button?

Note: I'm looking for a **keyboard shortcut**, not a mouse action.

Comment: The usual keyboard shortcut to paste the `PRIMARY` selection is shift+insert. The problem in Firefox may be related to how GTK+ decided to associate shift+insert with the `CLIPBOARD` selection. [GNOME bug 643391](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=643391) has patches to allow shift+insert to be remapped to paste from the `PRIMARY` selection. I did not try these patches yet, but I'll give them a try at some point, as this now tends to break my interaction with all GTK+-based applications...

Comment: there is a similar question in the unix board, did you try the proposed solutions? http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11889/pasting-x-selection-not-clipboard-contents-with-keyboard

Answer (score 2):

You can bind the following command to a key, it should make your firefox selection available to other programs:

```
xsel -b|xsel
```

and vice versa

```
xsel|xsel -b
```

Answer (score 1):

X11 has multiple clipboards: Selecting text with the mouse fills the "Primary Selection" and clicking the middle button inserts it. For Ctrl-V/Ctrl-C most programs use the "Clipboard", Shift-Ins seems to sometimes use the Primary Selection, sometimes the Clipboard.

So it's easier to not use Shift-Ins but either the Mouse or Ctrl-V/Ctrl-C to copy text between different applications.

Comment: If you're in an xterm, for example, the primary selection is your only option.

Comment: "It's easier" is quite relative to the tools you normally use. Depending on the tools you use, it may be easier to not use Ctrl-V/Ctrl-C.

Comment: middle mouse button. that's what I use. (click the wheel)

Answer (score 0):

In Linux, clicking the middle button (or scroll wheel) on the mouse should paste the contents of the Unix clipboard.

If you don't have a middle button on your mouse, clicking both the left and right buttons at the same time is often set up to emulate a middle-click.

Comment: Is there a way to do it *without* taking your hands off the keyboard?

Comment: try Shift + Insert

Comment: @spinus I think the whole point is that `shift+insert` does *not* work with firefox.

Answer (score 0):

The [autocutsel](http://www.nongnu.org/autocutsel/) util helped me...

I run this in my X startup script (~/.Xclients):

> autocutsel -buttonup -fork

You can test it first in a terminal like so:

> autocutsel -verbose

This util syncs CLIPBOARD with CUT_BUFFER0 (and vis-a-versa), so that a
selection in rxvt (my "xterm" of choice) will paste in Firefox using its
standard hotkeys.

Comment: But then you'll lose the distinction between those clipboards.  I tend to use the mouse selection for more temporary stuff.
Given that, clipit (https://sourceforge.net/projects/gtkclipit/) is a nice clipboard manager, which would provide this feature, too.

Comment: "vice versa": https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vice%20versa